# How can I prevent the window from scrolling when changing states with AngularJS UI-Router?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

With `ui-router` whenever the user navigates between states the browser window always scrolls to a seemingly random location. It seems to be worse when there are multiple `ui-view`s in play. How can I prevent this from happening?

Answer (score 1):

The `ui-view` `autoscroll` parameter controls this. By setting `autoscroll="false"` in all of your `ui-view`s the browser will not scroll when navigating.

[http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-router/site/#/api/ui.router.state.directive:ui-view](http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-router/site/#/api/ui.router.state.directive%3aui-view)

Answer (score 0):

Based on your question, I bet you actually want to set `autoscroll="true"`, which will scroll the view to the top after a transition, rather than staying at whatever position you happened to be scrolled to in the previous state - which can feel very random.